# how can I download IOS Iphone app via apple store apps link in any third party website directly

Tags: security, iphone, ipad, ios

I 'm pretty new to bug bounty and I want test Iphone app in MobSF(mobile security framework) for static analysis in Ubuntu 20.04 but I don't have a Iphone and macOS.
Is there any way to download latest Iphone apps without apple store .
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can use online software testing platforms. One suitable choice is [www.browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com).